# Gevent/greenlet closes socket when returned from connection handler.

Tags: python, sockets, real-time, gevent, greenlets

In gevent 1.0.2 , i am using StreamServer , and when handling a connection i am  keeping sockets in a dict to send events waiting on queue,    this works fine in 1.0.2 , but not in the latest version 1.1.x the socket just closes when returned from the  connection handler. How can i make this work with latest gevent in python.

```
def add_listener(self, stream_id , socket):
    socket.send(OK_200)
    self.event_listeners[stream_id][socket] = True
```

I am just keeping open sockets in a dictionary, broadcast events when there are some events. This works fine in 1.0.2 version , but with the latest 1.1.x  just closes this socket when returned from connection handler.

Answer (score 0):

Got help from IRC ,

```
<champax> think you hit : https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/594
<champax> you myay have to override do_close
<champax> *may
<pigmej> no, just don't return from handler
<champax> yeah working too
<ahbinav> i am waiting on a queue for events and broadcasting to list of sockets when event arrives in the queue. So, overriding do_close should do for me. I will try that.
```

The behaviour is documented. override do_close with nothing in the streamServer is the answer that worked for me.